# Do multiple alleles undergo crossover?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics

For a reference, point 3 of this article: https://www.biologydiscussion.com/genetics/multiple-alleles/multiple-alleles-meaning-characteristics-and-examples-genes/35452

According to google Bard and some other sources: Crossing over does not occur among multiple alleles because the alleles are present in the same locus of the homologous chromosome.

But I dont understand why can't they undergo cross over? In my slides of population genetics, it is written as a characterstic of multiple alleles, that is they can't undergo crossover.